# How to return animation of humberger icon

Tags: android, animation, android-actionbar, android-animation, toolbar

I just make my first steps in android programming and i need a help!

I created a navigation drawer and it opened/closed with animation of humberher icon automatically. Then i decided to make damping effect to toolbar. My toolbar became dark. I used code below. After that i had that effect but animation of humburger icon **disappeared**. I don`t understand what happened. Can anyone help me to solve this problem. I want to **return animation of humberger icon**.

```
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            if(slideOffset<0.6){
                toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you using an `ActionBarDrawerToggle` as your DrawerListener?

Comment: humherher?? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=owrvqq9wFp0

Comment: @MikeM. yes i used ActionBarDrawerToggle.

Comment: @MikeM.Thanks i forget that super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset); Its work

Answer (score 0):

The animation you're describing is handled in `ActionBarDrawerToggle`'s `onDrawerSlide()` method. You've overridden the method without calling through to the `super`'s method, so the animation code isn't running. Simply add the `super` call to your method.

```
public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
    super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);

    if(slideOffset<0.6) {
        toolbar.setAlpha(1 - slideOffset);
    }
}
```